# Inaccurate sleep using C++11 on Windows

Tags: c++11, ffmpeg

I've been using C++11 sleep to give the interval between video frames. This method I've been using makes playback elongated on Windows.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <sstream>


int main(const int argc, const char **args)
{
    std::stringstream sb;

    if(argc < 2)
        return 1;
    int fps = 0;
    sb << args[1];
    sb >> fps;

    if(fps <= 0)
        return 1;
    int i;


    while(true)
    {
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start, end;

        start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        for(i=0; i<fps; ++i)
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::microseconds(1000000 / fps));
        }
        end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto c = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
        std::cerr << c << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running that program with 60 gives about 1004~1006 on Linux and 1065~1075 on Windows. So, I'm guessing, after playing a 2-hour long video, more than a minute is passed than just 2 hours.

`timeBeginPeriod()` has no effect. Is using timer(like this [one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609(v=vs.85).aspx)?) is the only way to implement media players on Windows? What about on Linux? I think it's the right way considering the fact that ffplay uses `av_usleep()`.

So sad that there's no portable way.

Comment: *the only way to implement media players on Windows* well, no, for example we have a custom media player which needs to be frame correct so don't use timers/sleep at all, instead just rely on the renderer's sync to vertical refresh. Btw also see very first sentence in the documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 0):

> Is using timer(like this one?) is the only way to implement media players on ...

Using a high precision timer, such as the linked one, is one option. Another (but bad) option is to waste CPU cycles on busy waiting.